# The method getText() is undefined for the type ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I am trying to implement a popup window where you type text and it adds it to the ListView however I am getting the following error:

> The method getText() is undefined for the type ListView

My MainActivity.java code is as follows:

```java
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;
    private ListView result;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // components from main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrompt);
    result = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // get prompts.xml view
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final ListView userInput = (ListView) promptsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ListTitleDialogUserInput);

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Create",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // get user input and set it to result
                                    // edit text
                                    result.setText(userInput.getText());
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

        }

    });

}

}
```

Thanks for your assistance.

EDIT: The code for the for prompts.xml where the ListTitleDialogUserInput is defined is as follows;

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="List Title: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ListTitleDialogUserInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do `result.setText(userInput.getText());` where both result and userInput are Listview so getText or setText is not applicable..

Comment: Why is your `userInput` a `ListView`? Shouldn't it be an `EditText`? Can we see the file where the view with id `ListTitleDialogUserInput` is defined?

Comment: I copied a tutorial from http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/ and he used the EditText, but I want to display the result in a ListView. Can you help me please? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include prompts.xml code. Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: Well, in given example on link result is EditText not ListView, plz copy the complete code as it is... You will get the desired result

Comment: Just to clarify, the userInput is an EditText box in the popup window, and the Result is a ListView. Therefore, if getText or setText is not applicable, what is exactly? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, but I want the result to be displayed in a ListView. This must be possible?

Comment: You can add elements to a list; it's not clear to me what the issue is.

Comment: The issue is that the line of code discussed above throws up an error. "The method getText() is undefined for the type ListView" Can anyone provide instructions on how I can add the text entered in the prompt to the listview? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** put text directly in a ListView - the purpose of a ListView is to contain other Views.

Put a text-compatible view such as a TextView within your ListView, and call setText() on that.

If you really wanted a ListView that could directly display text, you'd have to make your own subclass which extends ListView and does some odd overlay or substitution magic to let you display text directly on it.

Comment: I do apologise, how would I go about putting a text-compatible view such as a TextView within my ListView? Can someone not provide some instructions or XML code about how I got get a popup window to appear, and then take the take entered in a textbox on the popup menu and add it to a list? Thanks once again.